# Convert string of bytes to float[] arry in C++

Tags: c++

I have a string which has bytes for a float array.
( I know where I got them, and their order 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th byte = float)
for about 10,000 floats

how can I convert this std:string into a float array with the 10000 numbers in C++

Comment: and you want a string to get converted into a float because???

Comment: Are the bytes in hex or in binary?

Comment: If you provide example input/output for a small test case (e.g. 5 floats), that would be helpful.

Comment: I been looking to cast my std:string s to a float[] without any luck on getting the right values for the array of floats back.

Comment: [code]
`float bytesToFloat(uchar b0, uchar b1, uchar b2, uchar b3)`
    {
    float output;

    *((uchar*)(&output) + 0) = b0;
    *((uchar*)(&output) + 1) = b1;
    *((uchar*)(&output) + 2) = b2;
    *((uchar*)(&output) + 3) = b3;

    return output;
    }
[code]

Comment: if I understand correctly, you will probably need to convert each 4 bytes into unsigned long using bit shifting (order matters!), then reinterpret_cast such long into float.

Comment: This is a bad question because it's very unclear what you're asking. Show the example of an input string and how it's supposed to be converted to floats.

Comment: out: ff♠@ffå@"²╩@τ) A @∟F   ----->

2.1 4.2 6.3434 8.01023 10000    .... very simple example

Comment: To get it to a string I did this if it helps
 `std::string s(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(std::begin(secondarray)),  // begin + end
              reinterpret_cast<char const *>(std::end(secondarray))); `

Comment: This is how you convert bytes to float:

    byte1*256^0 + byte2*256^1 + byte3*256^2 + byte3*256^3

Comment: yeah I see that is there a cast I can do it quickly than iterate through the whole string byte by byte?

Answer (score 1):

Modulo getting the byte order right, the following might be an idea:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> string_to_float(std::string const & s)
{
    assert(s.size() % sizeof(float) == 0);

    std::vector<float> result(s.size() / sizeof(float));

    if (!result.empty())
    {
        std::copy(s.data(), s.data() + s.size(),
                  reinterpret_cast<char *>(&result.front()));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This seems to garble the first few numbers?
1.09011e-038 0 8.67155e-039 0  --- 1.2 2 3 4  --- 1.3 2 3 4.3  ---
1 2 3 4.4  --- 1 2 3 4.5  --- 1 2 3 4.6  ---